# Azure web job - Implementing mutual exclusion in the cloud

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-webjobs

we are looking at building a system which has an area of code that requires mutual exclusion. In a dedicated hosting environment on a single server we might use this simple code that would run on multiple threads:

```
SomeAsyncOperation();
lock(locker)
{
  SomeSyncOperation1();
  SomeSyncOperation2();
}
```

Will this work in the cloud (assuming that webjobs may run across multiple physical machines)? Specifically Azure. If not how would this be implemented? So far I've looked at [CloudBlockBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.aspx) and the [competing consumer pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn568101.aspx). What are people doing to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: more info

Operation1 performs a lookup on a table, then Operation2 adds an entry to both a queue and a table if Operation1 finds nothing (otherwise an exception is thrown). To prevent duplicate items being added to a queue it is important that Operation1 and Operation2 run atomically across all threads (the application is running using async/await).

The following scenario is an example of how a race condition can emerge:

```
T1        T2
O1()      
          O1()
          O2()
O2()
```

On thread T1 operation1 has not found a duplicate. Thread T2 comes along and adds a duplicate. Threat T1 then runs operation2, which it should not have done.

Normally this could be prevented using a lock(), but I don't believe this will work across physical machines (such as in the cloud). Unless I'm wrong about this...

Comment: are the webjobs triggered or continuous?

Comment: It will run daily, but we would also like to trigger it manually. Does this change the behaviour?

Comment: What exactly is the nature of the locked resource that can only be accesed by one instance of the process? I'm asking because Webjobs can handle multi-threading but you can also [set them to a single-thread](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to/) mode, and if you don't scale up the App Service, you have a single-threaded unique Webjob. We use Queues for this scenario, with multiple Webjobs consuming the Messages but only one function can read one message at a given time, like the competing consumer pattern.

Comment: I added some more info

Comment: I know that azure supports distribute transactions(DTO). However, the below article indicates it is less than ideal when using transactions in queues. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clemensv/archive/2012/07/30/transactions-in-windows-azure-with-service-bus-an-email-discussion.aspx

Answer (score 10):

The [Azure WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk) has a declarative `SingletonAttribute` that can be applied to job functions to ensure that only a single instance of that function runs at any given time, even across multiple scaled out instances. Behind the scenes it does distributed locking via [Azure Blob Leases](http://justazure.com/azure-blob-storage-part-8-blob-leases/). More on Singleton can be found here in the [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton). Here's an example function (full sample can be found in the [samples repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/Functions.cs)):

```
    [Singleton]
    public static async Task ProcessWorkItem([QueueTrigger("workitems")] WorkItem workItem)
    {
        // Do your work - lock is maintained until this function completes
    }
```

This function will be triggered whenever a new queue message is written to the `workitems` queue. Before the function starts executing the **distributed lock** (blob lease) is acquired for the function, and held until the function completes. If another instance of the function is triggered concurrently, that instance will poll for the lock and begin once the lock is released.

There are additional options you can use with Singleton, including more fine grained lock scopes. For example, if the `WorkItem` type includes a `Region` property, `[Singleton("{Region}")]` will automatically bind to that value at runtime, so only instances of the function for items in the same region are serialized. You can also lock **across different functions**, which will allow you to annotate two different functions with the same Singleton scope so instances of both functions share the same lock.

Of course, as with in process thread synchronization, you have to consider how much **lock contention** you'll have in your system and design accordingly.

Comment: Great answer and very intersting to me currently. I think Singleton may be the answer to my problem but could you point me at more information about the lifecycle of WebApps and WebJobs and how a webjobs function is located and ran?

Comment: IMPORTANT: Currently this does not work on consumption billing plan (shared infrastructure). Worse it fails silently - basically it's ignored. I opened an issue to at least get the documentation updated - in future hopefully it will work https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3315

Answer (score 1):

I prefer service bus queue session capabilities. Session guaranteed  FIFO.
 Next work item is waiting processed before enqued item.